# Игровой процесс GTA San Andreas MP (SAMP)

Tags: windows, сервер, linux

Ребят доброго времени суток всем! У меня проблема с сервом! Я взял серв в аренду половину срока оплаты промотал потому что крутил этот мод и так и сяк и ничего толку. Думал в чём проблема и понял! Сервер моя сборка заготовлена под Виндоус а на хосте используется Линукс. ТАК ВОТ! КАК МНЕ ПЕРЕДЕЛАТЬ СВОЙ МОД ПОД LINUX?! Только прошу по-точнее и по-яснее ато искал сам и ничё не получилось в итоге!

Answer (score 1):

А что тебе мешает скачать версию сервера для линукса с сайта разработчика?